# Why does this substitution hold in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, substitution

Why does the substitution `X = Y, Y = [Y]` hold in the case of this query `[f(X)|Y] = [f(Y),X]`? How can `X` be `Y` and `[Y]` at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You are perfectly right that this "normally" cannot be the case.

However, for **efficiency reasons**, Prolog implementations typically omit the *occurs check* and therefore may yield somewhat unexpected results in such cases, allowing for **cyclic terms** by so-called *rational tree* unification.

See a simpler case:

```
?- X = f(X).
X = f(X).
```

You can use the ISO predicate `unify_with_occurs_check/2` to perform syntactic unification as you probably know it:

```
?- unify_with_occurs_check(X, f(X)).
false.
```

Notably, in SWI-Prolog, there is the flag `occurs_check` that you can set to `true` to enable the occurs check for *all* unifications. This is a very powerful and valuable feature:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true).
true.

?- X = f(X).
false.
```

You can even set the flag to `error` to catch cases where your program is **STO**, subject to occurs check:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, error).
true.

?- X = f(X).
ERROR: =/2: Cannot unify _G937 with f(_G937): would create an infinite tree
```